# DeserializeObject only deserialize partly

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, json-deserialization

Given a class

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public D_type D { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassTest>(json);`

Which works fine with the `D` object of class `D_type` it correctly parses as I need it. However, I don't want JSON.net to deserialize `D`, I want to do this instead

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public string D_json { get; set; }
}
```

I want to keep D as the json string and not deserialize it.

I am going to use a different deserializer right afterwards to convert it to something else. It seems pointless to deserialize to an object D_type and then serialize it back to json, only to deserialize it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I am able to do

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    public dynamic D { get; set; }
}
```

and then just use

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassTest>(json);
var json = obj.D.ToString()
```

but I am still curious if there is a better way, specifically one that returns a real `JSONObject` or something I can add properties to

Comment: You could make `D` `JObject`, but I'm not sure if that helps